# MvvmCross registering interfaces using IoC in Xamarin iOS7 and XCode 5

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm having an issue activating the IMvxMessenger using IoC. (Mac, Xamarin Studio, iOS7, Mono 3.2)

I have downloaded NPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross and loaded the N37 Maps project.

Compiled the project and it works fine.

I then added the Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Messenger.dll to the project and the following code to the app.cs Initialize just below the service IoC call.

```
CreatableTypes (typeof(IMvxMessenger).Assembly).AsInterfaces ().RegisterAsSingleton ();
```

I receive and error when compiling that says:
Failed to resolve parameter for parameter id of type Guid when creating Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Messenger.MvxSubscriptionToken

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't sound like it's anything to do with ios7

The line of code

```
CreatableTypes(typeof(IMvxMessenger).Assembly)
     .AsInterfaces()
     .RegisterAsSingleton ();
```

will:

- take all the creatable types in the assembly (ie any non-abstract types with a public constructor)
- will then find their interfaces
- will then create a new instance and register that as the singleton implementation for the interfaces.

For the Messenger plugin, that includes trying to new and register an `MvxSubscriptionToken` as an `IDisposable` singleton - although this fails as the public constructor for `MvxSubscriptionToken` requires a Guid (and you haven't told MvvmCross how to supply that - so the construction fails)

---

If you did want to just register specific types in an Assembly, then normally you'd add a `EndingWith("PostFix")` clause - like the default Mvx nuget templates do with `Services` as the postfix.

---

If you did want to just register a single specific class from an Assembly, then you'd often just do that as:

```
 Mvx.RegisterSingleton<IThing>(new Thing());
```

---

However, for plugins - which are just a convention-based set of rules placed on top of IoC - what you normally want to do is to call `EnsureLoaded()` on the plugin manager for the PluginLoader for that plugin.

The easiest way to do that is to include a Bootstrap file in the UI project - see the examples in N=8 - https://github.com/slodge/NPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross/tree/master/N-09-Location%20And%20Message/Location.Touch/Bootstrap - your application's Setup will use Reflection to find that Type and will then call `EnsureLoaded` on the plugin for you.

---

For more on IoC in MvvmCross, see https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/wiki/Service-Location-and-Inversion-of-Control

For more on plugins, see https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/wiki/MvvmCross-plugins

Comment: Very strange it has only just appeared, maybe it was related to updating the version of mono we are using.

Answer (score 5):

`IMvxMessenger` is a plugin and does not need to be registered for IoC in the way you are doing it. Plugins get registered by creating a `bootstrap` class for each of the plugins you want to use in your project like so:

```
public class MessengerPluginBootstrap
    : MvxPluginBootstrapAction<Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Messenger.PluginLoader>
{
}
```

Some plugins with platform dependent parts, such as the Visibility Plugin, need to be registered in a different manner on iOS, because it is silly:

```
public class VisibilityPluginBootstrap
    : MvxLoaderPluginBootstrapAction<Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Visibility.PluginLoader, Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Visibility.Touch.Plugin>
{
}
```

This way you should be able to use the types inside of the Plugin using IoC.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the plugin is installed in the Core project AND the Android project.